# Rust reporting "borrowed value does not live long enough" incorrectly?

Tags: ssl, rust

I have the following construction:

```rust
    let data = std::fs::read(args.base).expect("Could not read base file");
    for pem in Pem::iter_from_buffer(&data) {
        let cert = pem.expect("Reading next PEM block failed").clone();
        let x509 = cert.parse_x509().expect("Error decoding x.509 cert");
        certlist.push(x509);
    }
```

When compiled, I have the following error:

```rust
error[E0597]: `cert` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:20
   |
24 |         let cert = pem.expect("Reading next PEM block failed").clone();
   |             ---- binding `cert` declared here
25 |         let x509 = cert.parse_x509().expect("Error decoding x.509 cert");
   |                    ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
26 |         certlist.push(x509);
   |         -------- borrow later used here
27 |     }
   |     - `cert` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This seems strange to me because I'm not using `cert` on line 26, rather a derivative which should maintain a reference, and which hasn't errored (because I `expect`ed it away).

Furthermore, this is effectively a cut/paste from example code for the x509_parser [Pem component](https://docs.rs/x509-parser/latest/x509_parser/pem/index.html), which makes me wonder about the quality of the docs.

I can't seem to figure out how to force the `cert` variable to live longer.  Lexically, it's within the same for block - I'm not calling any functions that would cause errors as far as I can tell.

Comment: Seems that `.parse_x509()` just returns a reference, and you can make the object live longer by storing it. i.e. `let pems: Vec<_> = Pem::iter_from_buffer(&data).map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();` by doing so `pems` can live longer and then you can `for pem in pems.iter() {
        let x509 = pem.parse_x509().expect("Error decoding x.509 cert");
        certlist.push(x509);
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems strange to me because I'm not using `cert` on line 26, rather a derivative which should maintain a reference

You are correct, the `x509` keeps references to data from `pem`. This is a problem when storing it in `certlist` since it is *outside* the `for`-loop. The `pem` is destroyed at the end of each iteration while you are trying to preserve the `x509` beyond it.

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/x509-parser/latest/x509_parser/pem/index.html) you linked to reinforces this:

> Note that all methods require to store the `Pem` object in a variable, mainly because decoding the PEM object requires allocation of buffers, and that the lifetime of X.509 certificates will be bound to these buffers.

A solution would be to persist the `pem`s in a separate list. Something like this:

```
let data = std::fs::read(args.base).expect("Could not read base file");

let mut pemlist = vec![];
for pem in Pem::iter_from_buffer(&data) {
    let pem = pem.expect("Reading next PEM block failed");
    pemlist.push(pem);
}

let mut certlist = vec![];
for pem in &pemlist {
    let x509 = pem.parse_x509().expect("Error decoding x.509 cert");
    certlist.push(x509);
}
```

Comment: I come from a java background (well, C/C++ before that) and this finding is highly surprising!  Why would Rust language designers create a language that can be broken when a reference (that you might not even know about) leaves a scope?

Comment: I guess it prevents having to do mark-pass reference checks and GC overhead, but man that's weird.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Yeah, that's how it is. Rust's references are more like C/C++ pointers (or C++ references) except they are statically verified to be valid. Thus you get compiler errors when they aren't. They also don't impact the lifetime of their referent like you would be accustomed to in Java. And yes, they are facet of the overall goal to avoid GC.

Comment: So, your suggested process did not work.  It's now complaining that the `pem` in the `vec` is now erroring.  Furthermore, this is one of a few instances of this process that's inside an outer for loop.  How can I force scoping to be outside the for block?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I do not get a compiler error with the code I've shown

Comment: I initially missed the `&` in the `for pem in &pemlist`.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems like having to hold multiple references like this is a recipe for memory leaks.  If I (as I do in my toy application) want to remove items from the `certlist`, I would also need to have a parallel mechanism to remove items from `pemlist`.  In my case today, this process is small and short-lived, but I wouldn't want to maintain this in a long-lived process.